# Can you display content in Home Screen Quick Actions

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

Is it possible to have a Home Screen Quick Actions that would display the users current location for example.  Not necessary a MKMapView, but a string that determined by MKMapView...

Comment: See: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible, you can create a [`UIApplicationShortcutItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationshortcutitem) and then assign it to `UIApplication`'s property [`shortcutItems`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623033-shortcutitems):

```
let locationItem = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: "myLocationType",
                                             localizedTitle: "Location String")
UIApplication.shared.shortcutItems = [locationItem]
```

You also should take a look at Today Extension as mr. *shallowThought* recommended. If you implement it, the extension will be shown above your quick actions when user presses the app icon. In iOS 10 it require `UIApplicationShortcutWidget` key in the info.plist.